# Customize existing color bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, colorbar

How to move white portion of diverging color bar towards maximum value or minimum value.

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0,vmax=600)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 1))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)
cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cm.PiYG,
                                norm=norm,
                                orientation='horizontal')
cb1.set_label('Some Units')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`TwoSlopeNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm.html) normalization class

```
In [5]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
   ...: import matplotlib as mpl 
   ...:  
   ...: norm = mpl.colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=450, vmin=0, vmax=600) 
   ...: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 1)) 
   ...: fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5) 
   ...: cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=mpl.cm.PiYG, 
   ...:                                 norm=norm, 
   ...:                                 orientation='horizontal') 
   ...: cb1.set_label('Some Units')
```

[image]